# Migrating to new cms. Old cms moving to another subdomain. Dealing with links with htaccess (IF/THEN)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, migration, subdomain

The situation is following:

I am moving to a new CMS. Before complete migration from old one to new i decided to start beta version of new one.
So now i have:

- old -> http://www.myweb.com
- new -> http://beta.myweb.com

But soon old one will be renamed to http://old.myweb.com and new one to http://www.myweb.com , so:

- old: http://www.myweb.com -> http://old.myweb.com
- new: http://beta.myweb.com -> http://www.myweb.com

Difference in the links at the moment is following:

- old -> http://www.myweb.com/content/crab-goes-home-5
- new ->
  http://beta.myweb.com/stock-video/crab-goes-home-5-8523.html

(*as we see, new url has "stock-video" instead of "content". Also in the end of new url  is addition "-8523" which is unique, dynamically generated id.)

I want to achieve following:
I don't want to shut down old website(because of SEO), also because new web will have only 80% of old one website's content.

So if user enters(after all migrations) i.e. URL "http://www.myweb.com/content/crab-goes-home-5" and the page will be missing, then user must be redirected to http://old.myweb.com/content/crab-goes-home-5 (because this page will not exist on the new system, but still exist on the old one).

Any help and comments are welcome!
Thanks

Comment: There is one big problem with this, if your CMS redirects everything to a page handler let's say index.php, then I am afraid it won't be possible to have a simple rule to redirect the missing pages and you would have to do a manual rule or use a plugin. For instance WordPress have a plugin that catches 404 pages and allow you to set where u want to redirect it to.

Comment: Damn, really, the hardest part is here: "-8523.html", new CMS display item's page by this id, but the old CMS displays item's page by name.... Och.. it seems that Prix you are right - need something more difficult.

Comment: moving from wordpress to cmsaccount.com script